# Service extension writing to core data but nothing found in app

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, xcode9, xcode9.2

So I currently have an service extension setup that write data to CoreData (Or I believe it does).  Given that the xcdatamodelid is shared with both targets can I not write in one and read in the other?

Here is how I create the NSPersistenContainer in both targets:

```
lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "commonName")
    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    })
    return container
}()
```

And here is how I add an entity:

```
func addEntity(uid: String, status: String) {
    let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
    if let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: EntityNames.alertNotificationEntity, in: context) {
let managedObj = NSManagedObject(entity: entity, insertInto: context)
        managedObj.setValue(uid, forKey: CoreDataEntityKeys.AlertNotificationEntity.uid)
        managedObj.setValue(status, forKey: CoreDataEntityKeys.AlertNotificationEntity.status)
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

I don't get any fatal when a notification comes in and the addEntity method is used.

In my appDelegate when I try to print the values out it says it's just empty.

What am I doing wrong?  Is it not possible to share the CoreData between the Applications target and the service extensions target?

Edit:
I should add that I have already tried to setup what is outlined in [How to access CoreData model in today extension (iOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25408472/9505315)

Answer (score 0):

Data/File between the app and extension can be shared using App group.
Check [Share data between app and extension](https://agostini.tech/2017/08/13/sharing-data-between-applications-and-extensions-using-app-groups/)

Comment: App groups have already been setup and UserDefaults sharing between the two targets (main app and NSE) is working but NOT CoreData though.